# How to get physical directory path to path created by server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

I have an asp.net mvc web application that I deployed to a server. The app has an exe file that I keep in a known parent directory on my local machine and I call it using MapPath like this:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/parentDirectory/");.
```

The problem is, the server where I deploy to, doesn't keep the file in the same directory and I therefore have no way of calling it during compile time using this method. Is there any way I can call the exe file dynamically just by its name or another way to get the server's path?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath is called in runtime not during compile time and does exactly what you need.

Comment: The server removes the executable file and places it in a different folder which I don't know the name of.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use an appsetting in the web.config file and have the server admin add the path when your application is deployed.